# Regarding $_FILES['MF__F_0_0'], to what does MF__F_0_0 refer?

Tags: php, post, file-upload

My quandary arises from a function in a WordPress plugin called [NextGen Public Uploader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-public-uploader/).  In `handleUpload()`, the value of `$_FILES['MF__F_0_0']['error']` is used to determine whether or not the upload failed.  `MF__F_0_0` is not a named field in `$_FILES`.  Furthermore, I cannot find any reference or discussion of a key or attribute named `MF__F_0_0` in the source code or online.

The skeleton code of the function I am discussing is listed below.

```
//  Function: Handle Upload for Shortcode
public function handleUpload() {
    /* setup and other definitions */
    if ($_POST['uploadimage']) {            
        /* check_admin_referer(...) */
        if ($_FILES['MF__F_0_0']['error'] == 0) {
            /* process the upload */
        } else {
            /* mitigate failed upload */
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know to what `MF__F_0_0` specifically refers?
Does anyone know to where I should refer to read about the aforementioned key?

**edit**: It occurred to me that I should have included the associated code from the webpage used for making the POST.  The code was generated by the plugin using WordPress shortcode.

```
<div id="uploadimage">
    <form name="uploadimage" id="uploadimage_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8"><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="ae8639d6bf"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/chipamp-v3/gallery-better/">
    <div class="uploader">
    <input type="file" name="imagefiles" id="imagefiles">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="galleryselect" value="3">
    <div class="image_details_textfield">
    </div>
    <div class="submit"><br>
        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="uploadimage" id="uploadimage_btn" value="Upload">
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**edit #2**:  I deployed a test WordPress site with the relevant plugins/code [here](http://chipamp.com/testing/sample-page/) in case someone wants to try examining the situation themselves.  My efforts with Chrome's console and Firebug in Firefox have been unsuccessful, but I'm not certain I know what to look for.

**edit #3**:  On the off chance that JavaScript on the web page or the check-admin-referer call in PHP was complicating my situation, I uploaded an image and dumped the contents of `$_FILES` to the console (just before the if statement).  As you will see, there's no `MF__F_0_0` field.

```
Array
(
    [imagefiles] => Array
        (
            [name] => Koala.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpl65KuS
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 780831
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try a google search for 'wordpress mf__f_0_0'?

Comment: Yes, of course!  If my searching was inept and you can point me to a relevant search result, I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: If you can't find anything, check out the homepage (http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/nextgen-public-uploader/), you can probably get in contact with the dev via email and find what your are after.

Answer (score 2):

The keys of the `$_FILES` superglobal are the `name` attributes of the `input type="file"` elements in the HTML page.  `MF__F_0_0` is clearly the name given to the form field.

So this element:

```
<input type="file" name="MyFile">
```

would give this element:

```
$_FILES['MyFile']
```

This is an array that has the following key-value pairs:

- `name` – the name of the file on the client
- `type` – the MIME type of the file, as provided by the browser
- `size` – the size in bytes of the file
- `tmp_name` – the temporary name where the file is stored on the server until you move it
- `error` – an error code, if appropriate

Comment: `MF__F_0_0` is not used to name the element.  I updated my question with the code used for the POST.

Comment: @JordanGray Odd. My guess is that there must be some Javascript somewhere modifying things. Could you have a look at the DOM structure? (I.e. use an "inspect element" tool like Firebug or the Chrome console.)

Comment: I am able to examine the page, but I'm not certain what to look for.  Can you advise with more detail regarding my search (I can use either Chrome or Firebug in Firefox)?  Using Chrome to break on attribute mods I do not see anything..

Comment: There was no field named `MF__F_0_0` listed in `$_FILES`, at least not that I could see using `print_r()`.  Should I draw the conclusion that JavaScript modifying something cannot be the answer?